# C++ kafka client (rdkafka)

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using c++ kafka implementation from 
[C++ rdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) .
The question is about RdKafka::KafkaConsumer. How can I set the consumer to start from the beginning of a topic ?

P.S.
 The consumer example in the link is based on RdKafka::Consumer which is marked by "legacy only, use KafkaConsumer instead"

thanks ahead

Comment: Did you try "conf->set("auto.offset.reset", "smallest", errstr)" or "conf->set("auto.offset.reset", "earliest", errstr)" (for newer Kafka versions)

Comment: Yes. But it didn't help. When I restart my consumer I expect to read all messages from the beginning, (even those that I committed before prev. consumer application crashed)

Comment: did you resolve your problem? if yes how?

Comment: Any news about this one?

Comment: @GianLorenzoMeocci Please see the new answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how "auto.offset.reset" works. "auto.offset.reset" is only valid, if there is no valid committed offset. The flow is like:

1. start consumer (restart or after crash)
2. look for offset

   - if found, resume from offset
   - if not found, set offset according to auto.offset.reset.

If you want to read the whole topic on each restart, there is actually no reason to commit offsets at all. The purpose of committing offsets is to know where you left of, because you want to resume from this offset after restart.

Comment: OK, thanks.  What is the best practice to implement late-joining of a client ? ( e.g. I have a configuration message produced and then many consumers should read it at their own time and scheduling) I suppose not making commit will work, actually I also supposed that creating each consumer with group.id = GUID will give the same behaviour but it didn't.

Comment: I don't understand exactly. What do you want to do exactly? Seems to be a new question thought. To keep SO clean, you might want to start a new question.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I'm also experiencing this behavior. I'm using auto.offset.reset= false and a new random generated group.id with no consumer committing still didn't help. The consumer always reads the latests messages.

Comment: Values for `auto.offset.reset` are either "earliest" or "latest" or "none" (see http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) -- for librdkafka "none" is "error" (see https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/src/rdkafka_conf.c#L743)

Comment: ohh sorry, my mistake. I'm using "earliest". Still reads only new messages. The only workaround that I found is using rebalance_cb and setting assignment[0].offset = 0; but what if I have more than 1 partition? should I set all of them to 0?

Comment: Not sure why "earliest" does not trigger. Did you try "smallest". Maybe ask at the github page. And yes, if you have multiple partitions, you can set offset to zero for each partition. But I guess you should figure out the root cause -- if you use new group.id auto.offset.reset should work -- I doubt there is a bug, but you can never know :)

Answer (score 0):

I lost hours with this one, and the answer is, as is often the case, [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) :) Yes, you need to set the value of of the property `auto.offset.reset` to `smallest`, but the key question is - where?

From [this link](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Manually-setting-the-consumer-start-offset):

> The high-level Kafka consumer (KafkaConsumer in C++) will start
>   consuming at the last committed offset by default, if there is no
>   previously committed offset for the topic+partition and group it will
>   fall back on the **topic configuration property** auto.offset.reset which
>   defaults to latest, thus starting to consume at the end of the
>   partition (only new messages will be consumed).

Notice the words in bold, what I was doing wrong was invoking this:

```
rd_kafka_conf_set(_conf_handle, key, val, _errstr, sizeof(_errstr));
```

instead of this:

```
rd_kafka_topic_conf_set(_topic_conf_handle, key, val, _errstr, sizeof(_errstr));
```